# Adding to Dictionary inside a For Loop

Tags: swift, loops, dictionary, for-loop

I'm working with a swift playground for a project at Treehouse. I'm having trouble with adding an additional key:value pair to a dictionary inside of a for loop. Here is the code that I have:

```
var counter = 0
for (var player) in experiencedPlayers {
counter += 1
if counter % 3 == 0 {
    for team in 1...3 {
        switch team {
            case 1:
                teamSharks.append(player)
                player["Team"] = "Sharks"
            case 2:
                teamDragons.append(player)
                player["Team"] = "Dragons"
            case 3:
                teamRaptors.append(player)
                player["Team"] = "Raptors"
            default: break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This method does not error out, but it should be adding "Team": "Sharks", etc. to the player's dictionary but it is not. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's but you are then overriding the value of "Team" with  "Raptors". Every time you do player["Team"] = "NewValue" you are replacing what ever value it was before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify `player` before appending `player`.

```
    switch team {
        case 1:
            player["Team"] = "Sharks"
            teamSharks.append(player)
        case 2:
            player["Team"] = "Dragons"
            teamDragons.append(player)
        case 3:
            player["Team"] = "Raptors"
            teamRaptors.append(player)
        default: break
        }
    }
```

This is because `player` is a value type.

Note that will not have any effect on the data stored in `experiencedPlayers`, only the `teamSharks`, etc. arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Because player is declared inside the scope in your for..in only. So as soon as you try to modify it it will work only inside this scope, it's like a copy. If you want to modify you need to reassign your player in your experiencedPlayers with your modified object